# How to decrypt Turing' code version 1 as explained in MIT6.042

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I am self-studying MIT6.042j Mathematics for Computer Science. And I have copied the below text from the reading of chapter 04:

> The Nazis see only the encrypted message m* = m.k, so recovering the
> original message m requires factoring m*.

Could you explain how we can decrypt the encrypted message? I did not understand what does it mean that

> recovering the
> original message m requires factoring m*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $m^*=m\times k$ where $m$ and $k$ are both large primes, a recipient of the encrypted message $m^*$ who knows the secret key $k$ recovers the message $m$ by computing $m=\frac{m^*}{k}$. An adversary who is ignorant of $k$ but intercepts $m^*$ can recover both $m$ and $k$ if $m^*$ can be factored. See Chapter 1 [here](http://web.mit.edu/neboat/Public/6.042/numbertheory2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you explain what does factoting m* mean? That is my point of concern.

Comment: @AhmedKhalidIsmailMohamed Factoring an integer is the process of finding all of it's prime divisors and their exponents (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactorization.html).